# Create a Dynamic DropdownList in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

I Want to Create a Dynamic Dropdown list in the button Click Event and the drop downs having the
same values

Please Suggest me to get the Solution

Thanks in Advance

Comment: make more clear your requirement

Comment: Create a drop down list whenever the button click event is fired
and the Drop down list having the same list ..

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList dl = new DropDownList();
        dl.AutoPostBack = true;
        dl.Items.Add("Mike");
        dl.Items.Add("John");
        dl.Items.Add("Ajai");
        dl.Items.Add("Vir");
        dl.AutoPostBack = true;
        dl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(OnSelectedIndexChanged);
       form1.Controls.Add(dl);
    }
```

[image]